# context menu command for treeview item node

Tags: wpf, xaml, command, contextmenu

In the markup below, I am using context menu for a node of a treeview in a hierarchical template. The problem is that I want to bind the context menu items to individual commands but since i am using context menu item style there is no other way to bind the commands to the menu items. how do i bind them to commands defined in the root of the view model.

```
 <HierarchicalDataTemplate  x:Key="NodeTemplate">
            <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                <StackPanel.ContextMenu>
                    <ContextMenu>
                        <MenuItem Header="Copy">
                        </MenuItem>
                        <MenuItem Header="Paste">
                        </MenuItem>
                        <ContextMenu.ItemContainerStyle>
                            <Style TargetType="MenuItem">
                                <Setter Property="Command" Value="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource FindAncestor, AncestorType={x:Type UserControl}}, Path=DataContext.Copy}"/>
                                <Setter Property="CommandParameter" Value="{Binding Tag}"/>
                            </Style>
                        </ContextMenu.ItemContainerStyle>
                    </ContextMenu>
                </StackPanel.ContextMenu>
                <TextBlock Text="{Binding Path=Label}" Style="{StaticResource TreeTextStyle}" ToolTip="{Binding Path=Description}" Tag="{Binding Path=Tag}">
                </TextBlock>
            </StackPanel>
</HierarchicalDataTemplate>
```

Answer (score 0):

Why not just:

```
<MenuItem Header="Copy" Command="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource FindAncestor, AncestorType={x:Type UserControl}}, Path=DataContext.Copy}>
```

Edit: you're right it doesn't work because it is a ContextMenu, and a ContextMenu is drawn outside the Visual Tree of its `PlacementTarget` element, therefore `FindAncestor` doesn't work. Try the following:

```
Command="{Binding Path=DataContext.Copy, Source={x:Reference view}"/>
```

make sure you give an `x:Name="view"` to the actual view.

Comment: that does not work for some reason. there are already few posts regarding that.